# Setting up reverse proxy for firewall

Tags: python, security, server, web-applications, ids

I have created an simple web application firewall that can detect multiple types of attack using ml and I want to test it . FOR that I I have  set up this firewall at front of website such that it will intercept request going for website and allow only legiment traffic .

I set-up the revsered proxy server for this using appache (on windows) but didn't work
Any solution
Note :the firewall was made as and web application too ,I can't provide detail code here

Comment: Without any details, I don't see how you expect anyone to help with this. No amount of bounty can solve that problem.

Comment: It also doesn't sound like a programming problem, it sounds like an apache configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try NginX,
here is a sample code

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:your_webapp_port;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

consider running the website with https for security.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of success many years ago using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs/what-is-ngrok/) for a reverse proxy - might be worth a shot, if you're still working on this. (or if anyone else comes across this question)